# Preview Form Result With Ajax, jQuery and API

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a form where customers can generate a quote for my products. However I want them to be able to preview the quote cost before they submit it to be finalized. I have an API built like this

```
sitename.com/api/cart?model=1&height=700&width=550&cable_length=1&quantity=2&finish=polished_brass&rails=4&exit=top&concealed=0
```

with the get variables being the same as the form element names. The API just retrieves a number which I want to display next to the form when you click a button.

How would I go about doing this? I'm new to Ajax :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain if your question is how you pass the form data in the link or how you handle the returned result to display it. Anyway, you can:

```
$('#myform').serialize();
```

which returns the form values encoded in url form, and then use that on the url of a `jQuery.ajax()` request:

```
$.ajax('sitename.com/api/cart?' + $('#myform').serialize(), {
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        // The result is an HTML page, just paste it inside the "result" div:
        $('#result').append(html);
    }
});
```